# Relationship between the Frobenius Norm of AB and BA?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, normed-spaces

Assume $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ is a $n\times m$ matrix, $B\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is a $m\times n$ matrix, $\|AB\|_F \neq \|BA\|_F$ is definitely true at the most cases, but is there any rate between $\|AB\|_F$ and $\|BA\|_F$?

Comment: The rate would be related to $n, m$

Comment: The spectral radius of $AB$ equals that of $BA$, so you could say that 
$$\large{
\lim_{k\to\infty} \bigg\|(AB)^k\bigg\|_F^{\frac1k}
= \lim_{k\to\infty} \bigg\|(BA)^k\bigg\|_F^{\frac1k} \\
}$$

Answer (score 1):

They can be arbitrarily different. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2452187/191112). Take
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} x & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \qquad B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & y \end{pmatrix}
$$
for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Then
$$
\|AB\|_F = \sqrt{1+y^2} \qquad \|BA\|_F = \sqrt{1+x^2}.
$$
So I don't see any relationship between the two without further constraints.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are random matrix, for example, with iid entries, does the rate can be computed in probability?

Comment: That is a very different question.